# WPF ListBox.UnselectAll() doesn't clear visual state

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

I'm trying to build a ListBox which allows the user to unselect the item.

This is my XAML code:

```
<ListBox Name="MyListBox"
                ItemsSource="{Binding MoeglicheHauptspeisen}"
                SelectionMode="Single">
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Width="200"
                                Height="200"
                                Background="{StaticResource Braun}"
                                MouseDown="Speise_Gedrueckt">
                        <TextBlock Margin="0 50 0 0"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                   Text="{Binding SpeiseTyp}" />
                        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Beschreibung}" />
                        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Preis, StringFormat={}{0:C}}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

And my code-behind:

```
private void Speise_Gedrueckt(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
       MyListBox.UnselectAll();
    }
```

I can unselect the item by clicking on it again, it does set SelectedIndex to -1 etc., but it doesn't clear the border that the selected item has in the ListBox itself.

I did google a lot but nothing I found did change that fact. I tried to set the border/background of the item which is selected via a style.setter, but it also didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure when do you want to clear the selected item so I added a button with the EventHandler:

```
   <Button Width="100" Height="40" Click="Speise_Gedrueckt"></Button>
```

Now set the SelectedItem to null when the button is clicked:

```
 private void Speise_Gedrueckt(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
 {
        MyListBox.SelectedItem = null;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The "Speise_Gedrueckt" handler is the Click-handler of every ListBox item. What the handler does is checking if the SelectedItem of the ListBox is the one the handler is handling. If so, then unselect all. This should bring the behaviour of being able to "unselect" a selected item. It does set the values correct, but doesn't clear the visual state, which means that there is still a border around the former selected item

Comment: I tried to use a Button instead of a direct StackPanel as ItemTemplate for the ListBox items now and it worked. Why does it not clear the border of a StackPanel tho? Is it more of an focus than selected issue?

Answer (score 1):

Pay attention that Listbox item has 3 visual states - Selected, Not selected, and Focused. Even if you deselect Listbox item through code-behind, keyboard focus will still be there (assuming that you selected it by clicking on it). That's why some kind of visual indicator will be shown.

Comment: Yes, that's the focus visual. You can set focus to some other UI element and that focus visual is gone.